# Second book on probability. Recommendations

Tags: probability, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book on probability to remind the subject. I have the Feller, which is very nice but many of the basic parts are a little bit boring. My background is theoretical physics, so I'm looking for a text not so focused in applications (e.g. not machine learning or data science), but something that provides a decent background to the theory without sacrificing too much intuition.

I don't know anything on measure theory, so if a recommendation includes an introduction/use of the topic it will be very nice.

Comment: Probability and Measure by Patrick Billngsley,  Probability and Measure by K R Parthasarathy

Comment: I haven't read it yet, but Ross's book [A Second Course in Probability](https://www.amazon.com/Second-Course-Probability-Sheldon-Ross/dp/0979570409/ref=sr_1_10?qid=1646818027&refinements=p_27%3ASheldon+Ross&s=books&sr=1-10&text=Sheldon+Ross) might be good. It is fairly theoretical and it uses measure theory. A more introductory book that I like a lot, and which does not use measure theory, is Blitzstein and Hwang: https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110/home